# What does 'wishing bedbugs upon someone' mean?

Tags: meaning

> Fury as ‘explosive’ files reveal largest oil companies contradicted public statements and wished bedbugs upon critical activists

Is it an idiom or used [here](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/sep/17/oil-companies-exxonmobil-chevron-shell-bp-climate-crisis) in the literary meaning? There isn't such an idiom on dictionaries. What does it mean if it's used figuratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is used literally. To wish *someone or something* upon (or on) *someone* is to express the wish or hope that the thing mentioned happens to that person or persons. Someone connected with the oil companies must have said or written 'I hope they get bedbugs' about the activists. Generally the thing being wished is something bad, e.g. illness, death, or bad luck. Sometimes, when we hear that something very bad has happened to someone, we might say 'I wouldn't wish that on my worst enemy'.

If we wish someone on someone else we express the hope that the first person or persons mentioned will affect the second person or persons in some significantly bad or unwelcome way, e.g. to wish the police on an annoying neighbour, or to wish your annoying uncle on your cousin for the summer (rather than yourself).

> wish (someone or something) on (someone)
>
> idiom
>
> to want (someone) to have or be affected by (someone or something bad
> or unpleasant)
>
> *I wouldn't wish that terrible illness on anyone.*
>
> *I wouldn't wish that man on any woman.*

[Wish (someone or something) on (someone) (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wish%20%28someone%20or%20something%29%20on%20%28someone%29)